# How to rotate Puma Ruby web server logs (stdout and stderr)?

Tags: ruby, puma

In the Puma.rb file (Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files specified)

```
# stdout_redirect '/tmp/tistdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr'
stdout_redirect '/tmp/batman_stdout', '/tmp/batman_stderr', true
```

Can you please tell me the option to enable log rotation (for the puma web serve)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the webserver itself. It’s the target OS responsibility [`man logrotate(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for the reply. I just read few forums regarding logrotate.  I thought maybe Puma server have a plugin or configuration option to provide logrotate feature.

Comment: Why would the webserver double the functionality provided by any OS out of the box?

Comment: Hi @amitbhosale I found this tutorial pretty useful when starting out with logrotate https://gorails.com/guides/rotating-rails-production-logs-with-logrotate

Comment: @mudasobwa True, I read Nginx article posted (How To Configure Logging and Log Rotation in Nginx). They have suggested use logrotate

Comment: @dave-k  thanks for the sharing a very informative link